# Transferring perl modules (RHEL)

Tags: perl, module, cpan, data-transfer

I have need to install a couple perl modules onto my test environment (JSON and JSON::XS).
However, the test environment, which mirrors production, can't have gcc installed.
I do have a dev environment with gcc installed. I've used CPAN to download and compile these modules.

The issue is, how can I migrate them now from my dev environment to my UAT (and ultimately production) environments? All the environments are identical architecture, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these modules are available pre-packaged for RHEL. They are in the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository. Once you've configured your system to use this repository then installing the modules is as simple as `sudo yum install perl-JSON perl-JSON-XS`.

If you or your management are uncomfortable with using third-party repositories, then another option would be to download the tarball from CPAN and build your own RPM using somelike like [cpanspec](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Perl/cpanspec) and rpmbuild.

If you're working on a Red Hat system then using the native packaging system is almost certainly the easiest way to get software onto different environments.